# Is it possible to add a base64 data in file tag using javascript in safari?

Tags: javascript, html, safari, webkit, input-type-file

Is there any possible way to add a base64 data path in place of file tag `<type="file">` using javascript in safari?

I know the security reason it is not writable but looking for any patch or solution if available.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: No. There is only one way to change the fileList and that is with another fileList. There are two roundabout ways to get them using ClipboardEvent or DataTransfare but safari don't support either one of them.